# "No such module" Error in Cocoapods to Swift Package Manager Migration

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I have been tasked with migrating a very useful Cocoapod to SPM, and have been trying to follow the tutorials out there by the book. However, I have found that the lone dependency for the Cocoapod is not registering in the frameworks generated by the swift package init command, and can thus not be imported. I think the requisite files to solve this problem are the .podspec of the existing pod, and the package.swift file that I have just created, so I will include them below:

.podspec:

```
#
# Be sure to run `pod lib lint <name>.podspec' to ensure this is a
# valid spec before submitting.
#
# Any lines starting with a # are optional, but their use is encouraged
# To learn more about a Podspec see https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html
#

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = '<name>'
  s.version          = '0.0.17'
  s.summary          = '<name> contains some nice operators to make functional programming easier.'
  s.swift_versions   = ['4.0', '4.2', '5.0', '5.1', '5.2', '5.3']

# This description is used to generate tags and improve search results.
#   * Think: What does it do? Why did you write it? What is the focus?
#   * Try to keep it short, snappy and to the point.
#   * Write the description between the DESC delimiters below.
#   * Finally, don't worry about the indent, CocoaPods strips it!

  s.description      = <<-DESC
<pod_name> contains some nice operators to make functional programming easier. Many of these come from the excellent pointfree.co videos! Check them out for more!
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = '<homepage>'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Elliot' => '' }
  s.source           = { :git => '<source>', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.social_media_url = '<socialmedia>'

  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'

  s.source_files = 'Sources/<name>/Classes/**/*'
  
  # s.resource_bundles = {
  #   'LithoOperators' => ['<name>/Assets/*.png']
  # }

  # s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
  # s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'MapKit'
  s.dependency 'Prelude'
end
```

package.swift:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.2
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "<name>",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries produced by a package, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "<name>",
            targets: ["<name>"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "<name>",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "<name>Tests",
            dependencies: ["<name>"]),
    ]
)
```

I apologize in advance for if the placeholders are important, and this is my first StackOverflow post so knowledge of any conventions that I break are just as valuable as the answer to my question! The structure of the project mirrors what you would expect in a pod -> package migration, with Sources//Classes being the primary directory of interest, and an Example/ directory containing an example project for Cocoapod users.

Thanks so much!